# SIP video call Performance issue

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, chromium, ffmpeg, sip

I'm facing performance issue during video call made between RaspberryPI3 and Laptop, the video image from RaspberryPI3 are not running smooth and the overall CPU usage consumes more than 80%. Here below is my setup:

1. RaspberryPI3 with camera and MIC
2. Establish video call using doubango ( from chrome browser) on both RPI3 and Laptop.

### I tried the following on RaspberryPI3

1. enabled h264ify on chrome
2. increased GPU from 64,128,192

Is there a way to increase the video performance on RPI3? kindly help me to identify the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: are you 100% sure the video call is using h264 and not vp8/vp9?

Comment: @Jaromanda: I am not saying that, my question was how to improve the video call performance from RPI3. I tried with various options ( which I have already mentioned ) with no success.

Comment: well ... you say you enabled `h264ify` - and, as the Pi has gpu acceleration of h264, I thought that may be a good place to start - make sure the video is h264

Comment: Thanks, but either did not help, the performance remains the same there is no improvement

Comment: `either`? I only suggested one thing, so I gather you have confirmed that the video is indeed h264

Comment: no, it seems vp8

Comment: right ... so that's the problem ... the pi does vp8 on the CPU not the GPU, therefore you'll have poor results

Comment: Is there a way to change to h264 for better performance. I am using doubango "https://www.doubango.org/sipml5/call.htm?svn=170#" for video calls.

Comment: I don't know dubango, sorry